# How do I measure FPS of an android application that uses TextureView? (Am using OpenGL)

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, frame-rate, textureview

I have an infinite loop in my Render Thread. I tried measuring assuming that every call to `eglSwapBuffers` draws a new frame, but that is giving me results like 200 fps, which is not possible, right? The refresh rate cannot exceed 60?

Now I am doing the same thing but also using `surfaceTexture.getTimeStamp()` of the surfaceTexture of the SurfaceView. I consider a frame as having been drawn only if the timestamp returned in the previous iteration is not the same as in the current. Is the an acceptable way to measure? This is showing 50-55fps when I do no drawing. ie the loop has only `eglSwapBuffers()` and the `getTimeStamp` calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `surfaceTexture.getTimeStamp()` seems to be giving the correct result. I tested it by adding up all the differences between results returned by consecutive `getTimeStamp()` calls and it is equal to the total time the code ran for. This indicates that no frames are being left unconsidered etc.

Another solution I found is [this Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aatt.fpsm&hl=en). I do not know how it works but it is giving approximately the same results as the above method.